# saving the arrangement of my viewport

Tags: 3d-view

How do I save **only** the arrangement of my viewport into multiple windows **without** saving it
as a .blend file so that I can reopen it later on ? Also I would like to understand what does

```
ctrl+PgUp
```

here,i.e. what Arrangements it displays ?

[image]

Comment: Menu "File/Defaults/Save as startup file"?

Answer (score 0):

You can save a custom workspace by clicking on the little plus icon in the Header and choose Duplicate Current. (From looking at your screenshot I believe that is what you did already.) It will then be added to the Header and you can rename it by double clicking on it.

To save it, simply save your .blend file. This will allow you to re-open it in another .blend file by appending it.

Go to File > Append (or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> ). Locate the file you saved the Workspace in and double click on it. Open the folder titled "WorkSpace" and double click on the the custom workspace you made. It will now be added to the Workspace Header of the .blend file you are currently working in.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> flips through the workspaces in the Header from left to right, whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> flips through them from right to left.